# PHP session variable being reset in Android application

Tags: php, android, session, get

I am using a *session variable* in a php script that I am using in an Android application to store some information about a user. This implementation works when I run the php script in my terminal. However, when I try to run my application in Android Studio, the php session variable gets reset in between calls. How do I ensure that my php session is maintained in between calls in my android application?

I have done some research and I believe the problem lies somewhere in the code below (This is where I am creating my get request):

```
public class GetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


    String response = null;

    String pUrl = params[0];

    try {

        URL url = new URL(pUrl);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        if (response != null) {

        } else {

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

I have tried making the httpClient, cookieStore, and localContext variables static but the php Session variable was still reset.

I am instantiating my GetRequest objects like this:

```
public static String serverAsyncRequestGet (String params, String api) {
    String output = null;
    GetRequest gr = new GetRequest();
    try {
        output = gr.execute(api + params).get();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return output;
}
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem turned out to be simpler than expected. All I had to do was make a static HttpClient object that I would reuse each time.

No need to fool around with CookieStores or HttpContext.

This code works:

```
public class GetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



//initialize the httpClient to null so that we can check if it has been updated
//having one global httpClient allows us to use PHP session variables.
public static HttpClient httpClient = null;

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String response = null;

    String pUrl = params[0];

    try {

        URL url = new URL(pUrl);

        Log.v("URL", "URL " + url.toString());

        if(httpClient == null) {//if the httpClient has not yet been set....
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();//Create the HttpClient that will be reused each time

        }

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        if (response != null) {

        } else {

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```